# Not able to debug the PL/SQL Procedure in SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle18c

I am able to run the PL/SQL Procedure in SQL Developer?

**PL/SQL procedure**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE greetings 
AS 
BEGIN 
   dbms_output.put_line('Hello World!'); 
END;
```

**Here is the DB Logs:**

```
Connecting to the database Oracle_XXXX.
Hello World!
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database Oracle_XXXX.
```

But I m not able to debug the PL/SQL Procedure and getting the error logs?

**Here is the error DB Logs :**

```
Connecting to the database Oracle_XXXX.
Executing PL/SQL: CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP( '127.0.0.1', '63717' )
ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP", line 68
ORA-06512: at line 1
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database Oracle_XXXX.
```

Can any one suggest me how to resolve this?

Comment: I can't answer the network access issue, but your test procedure doesn't have anything in it to debug, so when you do get the debugger working it won't do anything. I suggest adding a variable and assigning a value to it.

Comment: At least it should stop at  dbms_output.put_line('Hello World!');  when i place the break point here.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson i would like to get rid of this issue. "SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP"

Comment: To be honest, I have never seen anyone successfully using the remote debugger, even though it is supposedly the main supported debugger and the old dbms_debug - which I use all the time - is limited and deprecated. I'm hoping someone can answer too.

Comment: Check my blog, https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/06/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-the-plsql-debugger/

Comment: Btw, have you ever checked out the questions related to ["ora-24247" tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-24247?tab=Frequent) ..?

Answer (score 2):

```
Connecting to the database Oracle_XXXX.
Executing PL/SQL: CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP( '127.0.0.1', '63717' )
ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
```

This is an error coming back from the database.

It is saying, in PL/SQL, you are attempting to connect to 127.0.01 on port 63717, but we are not allowing for outbound network activity from the database.

For the default debugger to work in SQL Developer, you will need to define an Access Control List (ACL) rule.

You can go through this process, OR you can use the DBMS_DEBUG debugger API, which has SQL Developer make a second database connection to do the debugging, vs having the database connect back down to your client.

I have instructions for both methods/routes here
https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/06/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-the-plsql-debugger/

For ACL specifically, I really like's Galo's post here
https://galobalda.wordpress.com/2014/02/17/sql-developers-plsql-debugger-and-oracle-12c/

Comment: Thanks alot Smith